# Mark a number invalid (besides -1): Infinity or NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan, infinity

I need to mark a number `foo` invalid and can't use `-1` because `foo` can be negative. *I still don't want to bother the compiler by changing the type.* Both `Infinity` and `NaN` satisfy `typeof === 'number'`, so I could use either? Are there any pitfalls with either?

Example: `NaN != NaN` (but there is `Number.isNaN`), but `Infinity === Infinity`.

I need to check whether the new number equals the old `foo`, so I would use `NaN` because it's shorter while semantically in my code both make sense.

Edit: Usage is to determine whether the cached value is still valid. (Note the original is written in Coffeescript.)

```js
someCachedGetter: (() => {
  let foo = NaN; let cache = null;
  return () => {
    let t = getFoo();
    if (foo === t) { return cache; }
    else { foo = t; return cache = expensiveOperation(); }
}})(),
```

Comment: NaN literally means Not a Number, so yes, use that. But it would have been nice to have some context as to *why* you need to mark a number as invalid. Maybe it isn't actually what needs to be fixed. It is impossible to tell without any code to look at.

Comment: Both Infinity and NaN are represented as floats.

Comment: `NaN` is usually reserved for the result of invalid operations (like `0/0`), it's not expected to be used as a placeholder like this. I think most people would use `null` for an explicit marker.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson edited.
@Barmar didn't know that NaN is also float. Thanks. Regarding null: `typeof null === 'object'`, poor practice.

Comment: Is this an XY problem?

Comment: @ksav possibly, by the very nature of the XY problem, I can't tell... Added usage.

Comment: To back @Barmar's suggestion: IMO `null` is the semantically most correct solution, since all other suggested values have very specific semantics. The `typeof` counter-argument seems odd to me, since it pretty much indicates that _any_ usage of `null` is "poor practice" (it always will be of a different type than the non-null value).

Comment: After seeing a snippet of your code, I agree with @Barmar. Use null.

Comment: @dr_barto not true, not *any* usage -- if the value to be placed will be an object, null is perfect. Exactly as in code in the question.

Comment: @n-smits the argument was that `typeof` returns a different type for null and non-null values, and this will also be the case for objects. Therefore the argument either is valid for all types, or for none; making a distinction between objects and primitives on this level is not suitable for JS (while it would be is a valid point in strongly-typed languages).